# Support for writing Spock tests in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spock

Are there any additional tools, plugins or anything helpful for writing/running Spock tests in Eclipse? Currently, it seems difficult to use.

I searched the web but found nothing, that would be helpful.
Spock plugin from eclipse marketplace isn't avaiable to download anymore and I didn't found any mirrors.

Comment: Have you looked at the Eclipse Marketplace? https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/spock

Comment: Yes, I wrote it in my question.

Comment: Yes, without linking to it.